# Why the Button's background does not change when I set its status?

Tags: android, view, background, selector

I made a Button with a `selector`.
The `selector` is as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_select"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Then, I set the button status to selected like this:

```
btn.setSelected(true);
```

But the Button's background is not changed to `btn_select`
Why?

Comment: Post your xml file content.

Comment: It seems you forgot to associate your Button with your selector in your layout.

Comment: Those are not important, so i didn't post.

Comment: `Those are not important`. You think so. But it actually is important.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the attribute `android:state_pressed="true"`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_select"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</selector>
```

If you specify `android:state_pressed="true"`, the background will be changed only when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_select"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</selector>
```

**And in your xml file**

```
android:background="@drawable/style_button"
```

**Use this inside your button tag**